# Apples TestFlight Crashlogs

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am kind of stuck here, Ive been trying to test my app update with the external testers using Apples newly bought TestFlight.

I've been testing it myself and with friends who've never had it crash on them(on 7.1+ or 8.0+ which is what the update is supporting)

I've submitted 3 times now, each with the response of rejected due to crash on launch. 
Which I use parse and crashlytics, neither of them give me any proof the app was installed or that it crashed.

Is there a way to get a crashlog from apple, I've emailed them, but they dont seem to have a lot of contact info for speaking to someone about this.